# How can I minimize the max of the sum of my columns?

Tags: z3, z3py

The problem that I'm trying to solve is simple (I guess :)), but because I'm new to z3 I'm always getting compile errors.

My problem:

```
[ [var_0_1, var_0_2, var_0_3,...]
, [var_1_1, var_1_2, var_1_3,...]
, [var_2_1, var_2_2, var_2_3,...]
]
```

My objective is to sum the value of the columns and then discover the max of all the sums and after that minimize that value and do that all over again until It's impossible to minimize more the max of the sum of all columns...

I hope that you understand my problem because my English is not very good :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get some vague *maxmin/minmax* idea from your problem description. Unfortunately, the iterated part of your problem is not very clear to me. Could you please try to give a formal description of your problem using mathematical notation? That should be pretty much universal and less ambiguous to understand.

Comment: Posting what you have tried might help as well; especially if you can minimize it to produce the "error messages" you're getting. Then we can help how to proceed from there.

Comment: Basically is this: minimize(max(sum(var01,Var11,Var21),sum(var02,Var12,Var22), etc...))

Comment: @AndreOliveira so this is a basic *minmax()* problem? I was confused by the *"...and to that all over again until i'ts impossible to minimize more..."* part.

Comment: yes that's what I'm trying to do.... ye forget that part of the "...and to that all over again until i'ts impossible to minimize more..."

Comment: @AndreOliveira I am still thinking that I do not understand your goal, so please bear with me. Let `x in 0..10`, `y in 0..5`, `t in 0..7` and your matrix `[[x+y],[x+t]` be of `1` row and `2` columns, what is the desired solution?

Comment: In this case because you only have 1 row, I want to know which collumn has a bigger value [x+y] or [x+t], and minimize that max value... Example: x= 2, y= 3, t=4, we get [5,6], now i want to get the max (6) and minimize that max(6). After minimize, the first time, imagine that we get [5,3] and now i want to minimize the max (5) until it's not possible to minimize my max anymore. Thx for your help! I hope that now you have understand my question

Comment: How is this different from minimizing the sum of all columns altogether? Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: I tried do that but It didn't work...

Comment: File "single_chargers.py", line 119, in <module>
    h = s.minimize(a)
  File "C:\Users\z003yrsf\ficheiros\Python_Scripts\chargers_proj\z3\z3.py", line 7358, in minimize
    return OptimizeObjective(self, Z3_optimize_minimize(self.ctx.ref(), self.optimize, arg.as_ast()), False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'as_ast'... I'm always getting this

Comment: I have put  "a" as an array that stores the sum of all the collumns a = [sum(v01,v11,v21),sum (v02,v12,v22), etc...] what do you think it might be?

Comment: Ok, that clearly doesn't work because `a` is not an element of some theory. We are almost there. Let `x in 0..3`, `y in 10..20`, `t in 10..20` and the matrix be `[[y+x],[t-x]]`, same format as before. Your algorithm can have more than one starting point (e.g. `y=13,t=7` or `y=10,t=10`) because the objectives are co-dependent. The sum `13+7` is equal to `10+10`. If the latter solution is to be preferred, then the goal of the optimization problem should be `min((sum_col_1)^2+(sum_col_2)^2)`. Correct? Do you have negative values?

Comment: yes and I don't have any negative values

Comment: Then you may use that function as optimization goal. However, since it is a non-linear function, it may be not very fast, or even result in an `unknown` result. In that case, you may want to try `min(sum_col_1 + sum_col_2)`, incrementally extract all solutions with the same global minimum value, rank these solutions according to the previous non-linear function and then pick the one with lowest rank. This might blow-up pretty quickly, though.

Comment: Sry for not telling anything... After talking with a friend of mine, i found that what i wanted was a min (max()) function and we made this `for y in zip(*time):
    z = sum(y)
    a = maxi(a,z)`  and the maxi function is `def maxi(a,b):
    return If(a>=b,a,b)` Do i post this as the answer of the problem? And many thx for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I thought that you were trying to solve some `minmax()` problem because you stated that you wanted to solve

> `minimize(max(sum(var01,Var11,Var21),sum(var02,Var12,Var22), etc...))`

in the comments. However, further requirements elicitation made it clear that it couldn't possibly be an instance of `minmax()`, so I ditched the idea and didn't think about it any further.

---

Now, your self-posted solution is an instance of `maxmin()` in disguise. I am not sure whether that really solves your initial problem. However, if that is the case, then I would advice you to try to use the following encoding instead of the `ite`-based solution [references: [tacas15](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/papers/tacas15.pdf), [tacas15_extended](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/papers/tacas15_extended.pdf)].

[image]

*(note: `cost` ought to be a new variable of the same type as the `cost_i`, which is declared for the purpose of solving the `maxmin()` goal. Every other `cost_i` is demoted from objective to a simple term)*

I believe that this approach has some chance to perform better than the other one.

---

**EDIT:** source code example with `a = 0`:

```
goal = Real("cost")
for y in zip(*time):
    s.add(sum(y) <= goal)
result = s.minimize(goal)
```

If you want to replicate the case in which `a = 50`:

```
goal = Real("cost")
for y in zip(*time):
    s.add(sum(y) <= goal)
s.add(50 <= goal)
result = s.minimize(goal)
```

Comment: That's a really clever encoding! Definitely avoids a whole bunch of calls to the optimizer. Nice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188990/discussion-between-patrick-trentin-and-andre-oliveira).

Comment: @AndreOliveira please keep the conversation in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

Function min(max()):

```py
def maxi(a,b):
  return If(a>=b,a,b)

a = 0
for y in zip(*time): #time is a list with many rows and columns
  z = sum(y)         #z receives the sum of the columns
  a = maxi(a,z)     

o.minimize(a)
```

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Do you think that this is the best solution to make a min(max()) function? And thx for the help!

Comment: The bias I accumulated through my experience tells me that the other encoding should perform better than this one. However, there is only one definitively correct answer, and it is to test it out yourself: compare the two approaches on a reasonable set of benchmarks and see what happens.